# How can I use Json.NET to deserialize objects by reference, when using a custom format for the reference?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have JSON in the following format:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Smith",
            "vet": [ "FOO", "VET-1" ],
            "animals": [ [ "FOO", "ANIMAL-22" ] ]
        },
        {
            "first_name": "Susan",
            "last_name": "Smith",
            "vet": [ "FOO", "VET-1" ]
        }
    ],
    "BAR": {
        "VET-1": {
            "vet_name": "Acme, Inc",
            "vet_id": 456
        },
        "ANIMAL-22": {
            "animal_name": "Fido",
            "species": "dog",
            "animal_id": 789,
            "vet": [ "FOO", "VET-1" ]
        }
    }
}
```

Some nested objects, or objects referenced more than once, are serialized as references.

The referenced objects are then included in the `BAR` array at the end of the JSON object, and identified in place by the `[ "FOO", "ANIMAL-22" ]` array.

(Both `FOO` and `BAR` are static constants, and the `ANIMAL-22`/`VET-1` identifiers are semi-random)

Unfortunately, this doesn't match how [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) already [serializes/deserializes referenced objects](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) and the [IReferenceResolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IReferenceResolver.htm) I could implement doesn't seem to allow me to adjust the behaviour enough ([it's fixed to use "$ref"](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonTypeReflector.cs#L51) for a start).

I've also tried writing a custom [JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) for the properties affected, but I can't seem to get a reference to the `BAR` property of the root object.

**Is there any way I can override [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize the JSON above into this kind of C# class structure?**

```
public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vet")]
    public Vet Vet { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("animals")]
    public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}

public class Vet
{
    [JsonProperty("vet_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vet_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Animal
{
    [JsonProperty("animal_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("animal_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("vet")]
    public Vet Vet { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("species")]
    public string Species { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Edit #1:** Although I give only `Animal` and `Vet` in my example, there are a large number of types referenced in this way and I think I need a 'generic' or type-agnostic solution that would handle any such occurrence of the array structure `[ "FOO", "..." ]` without needing to code for each C# type individually.

Comment: No, you cannot make this happen automatically.  Putting aside the hardcoding of the `"$ref"` property names, Json.NET is a single-pass serializer, but `"ANIMAL-22"` and `"VET-1"` look to be *forward references* to JSON objects appearing later in the file, and so will not have been read at the time the references are read.  You will need to manually postprocess the objects after deserialization to fix up such references, or preprocess the JSON into Json.NET's required format using LINQ to JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @dbc said in the comments, there is not an easy way to make Json.Net automatically handle your custom reference format.  That said, you *can* use [LINQ-to-JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JObjects) to parse the JSON, and with the help of a `JsonConverter` and a couple of dictionaries, resolve the references and populate your classes while still leaving most of the heavy lifting to Json.Net.  Here's the approach I would take:

1. Create a custom generic `JsonConverter` which can decode the `[ "FOO", "<key>" ]` reference format and return the corresponding object from a provided dictionary.  Here is the code for the converter:

   ```
   public class ReferenceConverter<T> : JsonConverter
   {
       private Dictionary<string, T> ReferenceDict { get; set; }

       public ReferenceConverter(Dictionary<string, T> referenceDict)
       {
           ReferenceDict = referenceDict;
       }

       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return objectType == typeof(T);
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           JArray array = JArray.Load(reader);
           if (array.Count == 2 && 
               array[0].Type == JTokenType.String && 
               (string)array[0] == "FOO" && 
               array[1].Type == JTokenType.String)
           {
               string key = (string)array[1];
               T obj;
               if (ReferenceDict.TryGetValue(key, out obj))
                   return obj;

               throw new JsonSerializationException("No " + typeof(T).Name + " was found with the key \"" + key + "\".");
           }

           throw new JsonSerializationException("Reference had an invalid format: " + array.ToString());
       }

       public override bool CanWrite
       {
           get { return false; }
       }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Parse the JSON into a `JObject` and build a dictionary of `Vets` from the `BAR` section of the JSON.

   ```
   JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);

   Dictionary<string, Vet> vets = data["BAR"]
       .Children<JProperty>()
       .Where(jp => jp.Value["vet_id"] != null)
       .ToDictionary(jp => jp.Name, jp => jp.Value.ToObject<Vet>());
   ```
3. Build a dictionary of `Animals` from the `BAR` section of the JSON, using the `ReferenceConverter<T>` and the dictionary from step 2 to resolve `Vet` references.

   ```
   JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
   serializer.Converters.Add(new ReferenceConverter<Vet>(vets));

   Dictionary<string, Animal> animals = data["BAR"]
       .Children<JProperty>()
       .Where(jp => jp.Value["animal_id"] != null)
       .ToDictionary(jp => jp.Name, jp => jp.Value.ToObject<Animal>(serializer));
   ```
4. Finally, deserialize the `users` list from the JSON, again using the `ReferenceConverter<T>` plus the two dictionaries (so actually two converter instances now, one per dictionary) to resolve all the references.

   ```
   serializer.Converters.Add(new ReferenceConverter<Animal>(animals));
   List<User> users = data["users"].ToObject<List<User>>(serializer);
   ```

Full demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uUuy7v

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and working demo! I think my use of "automatically" was a bad choice of words. Since there is a huge variety of classes I'm deserializing to, I am hoping for a "generic" or agnostic solution, that would handle any such occurrence of the array structure `[ "FOO", "..." ]` without needing to code for each C# type individually. In my example, I have only `Vet` and `Animal`, but in reality there are far more. I also have no guarantee that the type of a referenced object can be determined by inspecting the properties (as you have done in step #2 with `vet_id`).

Comment: I do think the concept of populating something with the contents of the `BAR` dictionary is the way to go. I'll need to defer the deserializing of each referenced _value_ until the `JsonConverter` is called for a property and the property type is known. But as far as I can tell, a  `JsonConverter` is triggered by a known type that is being deserialized _to/from_ rather than the existence of the array structure `[ "FOO", "..." ]` in the JSON.

Comment: Sorry, it's been more than a year, I should've accepted your answer as the most helpful answer a lot sooner!

Comment: @BenJenkinson No worries.